# JavaScript code not running in HTML5 document

Tags: javascript, html, komodoedit

I'm beginning HTML5 development, and I'm already in trouble with javascript in HTML code:

```
<script>

// javascript code

</script>
```

If i write my code in HTML only, there's no problem, As soon as I add javascript code, only HTML works but javascript doesn't seem to exist while debugging.

May I link some libraries for JS language? I tryied to create a separate .js file, same problem.

PS. I'm working with Komodo Edit

Thanks for possible solutions.

Comment: What is that *//javascript code*?

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Is javascript disabled (unlikely)? What do you see when you right-click and press view page source? Is the script element there? What about when you press inspect element?

Comment: I guarantee you that the code you posted is not all of your code needed to reproduce this problem, unless JavaScript is disabled in your browser.

Comment: ***remove the <!DOCTYPE html>*** , In my case it worked by removing it

Answer (score 3):

Take a careful look at this minimal example and compare with your own code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("this works");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code syntax is perfect, and it works if I print some words, or an alert message,the problem is about functions and methods(for loops, creating canvas, etc.). In a few words, I can't execute the code as a web application. Maybe, as a beginner developer, I'm not using javascript the right way

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your browser is allowing popups, and the java script....But you would have to post more of what your trying to do, so we could ensure your code is correct as well....